# Trigger not firing on subject line after Outlook gets a new email

Tags: slack, zapier

I'm trying to post a message to a Slack channel each time we receive a confirmed booking via email through Airbnb.

Tried Zapier, by scanning new emails with the subject "Reservation confirmed" sent to our Microsoft Outlook email. If the email has that subject then the zap should posts its contents (body) in the channel. However, the first step (trigger) doesn't recognize new emails.

This is what the Zap looks like:
[image: This is what the Zap looks like]

Step 1: check if a new email is received in Outlook ==> this is the test never passes, because it can't find sample data.
[image: Step 1: check if a new email is received in Outlook]

Step 2: filter emails that contain the subject Reservation confirmed (in Dutch)
[image: Step 2: filter emails that contain the subject Reservation confirmed (in Dutch)]

Step 3: post a message in a Slack channel
[image: Step 3: post a message in a Slack channel]

Comment: Hi Nanne! If you aren't getting an email then the issue is in trigger setup. Can you copy a screenshot of your zap trigger setup (with personal info hidden)? Also, make sure that the trigger emails are being sent to the right place (i'd disconnect the zap's outlook account and then sign in again while paying careful attention to the email address).

Comment: Hi @littlecoder thanks for your help. I included 4 images in my OP. It looks like the connection to Outlook can't be made, the test never runs....

Answer (score 1):

Your filter step has "text contains" option followed by the words. While that is logical from a human standpoint it can cause some problems with zapiers filter. Try filtering for each word separately like so:

```
Subject Contains(text) yourFirstWord
AND
Subject Contains(text) yourSecondWord
```

This will clear up your filter problem.

Also, double check that `subject` is not something you typed in but that it is the actual outlook output variable.

If it passes through the filter and still doesn't get to slack then the issue is elsewhere. You may want to post sample data if that doesn't work because it could be that the subject line has hidden whitespace (rare but has happened to me) or other values that is making it filter out. If that's the case I'll edit and update this answer.